# word boundary on non latin characters in php

Tags: php, regex, word-boundary, non-latin

This example works fine:

```
echo preg_replace("/\bI\b/u", 'we', "I can"); // we can
```

This one were russian letters are used does not work even though I use "u" modifier:

```
echo preg_replace("/\bЯ\b/u", 'мы', 'Я могу'); // still "Я могу"
```

So the question is what should I do to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PCRE (the library used by `preg_replace`), `\b` refers only to word boundaries in an ASCII sense, i.e., only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` are word characters.

If you want to match a `Я` character that has no letters, digits or `_` immediately before or after, you can use:

```
(?<![\p{L}0-9_])Я(?![\p{L}0-9_])
```

You still have to use the `u` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Word boundaries are [often counter-intuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173).